# Unable to install nvm on mac OSX - documentation appears to be innacurate

Tags: macos, node.js

So as per the documentation on https://www.npmjs.org/package/nvm installation consists of two steps. The first step is

```
$ npm install -g nvm
```

, the second step

```
export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

The second step is inaccurate, I do not have any folders called node_modules created after running the command.
I figured the `/usr/local/bin/nvm` or /`usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm` that appeared in my terminal have a file somewhere I need to add to the PATH but I am not sure which. When I go directly to `/usr/local/bin/nvm` and execute `./nvm ls`I get a message saying "local" not implemented yet.

This is what my terminal looks like:

```
Juans-MacBook-Pro:thefuck juan$ sudo npm install -g nvm
Password:
/usr/local/bin/nvm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm
nvm@0.0.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm
└── mkdirp@0.3.5
Juans-MacBook-Pro:thefuck juan$ ls
Juans-MacBook-Pro:thefuck juan$
```

I ran out of ideas of what I can do to successfully install npm & am now turning to the community for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need also do:

```
 git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
 printf "\n\n# NVM\nif [ -s ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ]; then\n\tNVM_DIR=~/.nvm\n\tsource ~/.nvm/nvm.sh\nfi" >> ~/.bashrc
 NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

All the details you could want are here: http://www.backdrifter.com/2011/02/18/using-nvm-and-npm-to-manage-node-js/